# how to design custom material design views in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I am developing an Android App. I am new to Android Material Design. Can anyone give me any lead on how to design custom material design views ?

Comment: Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

There are no proper design templates available in Android sdk. Tough you can try to explore them as some of them includes a few material design functionality. But if you want to develop your whole project with Material Design views then you can check out this library. You will get all the material design views here.[Material Design Library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)